# How does an electron interact with an electron neutrino?

Tags: electrons, neutrinos

An electron and neutrino come close and they exchange a W boson and then they change places.. but why? A neutrino has no electric charge, so how do they know to interact?

Comment: Because there are interactions that aren't electromagentic?

Comment: "They" don't know anything. "They" are not people. Electrons and neutrinos are linked trough the electroweak interaction, but what you are talking about is really just first order perturbation theory, which is fine for many applications, I guess, it's just not an actual physical process. It's merely a model approximation that makes sense for this limited case.